# Добавить трехугольник к блоку подсказка с border!

Tags: css3

Нужно создать подсказку с маленьким треугольником сверху:

html

```
        <div class="title">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
            <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Все знаках, составитель, пунктуация они предложения родного там большой великий на берегу рукописи, за рыбными то бросил заманивший взгляд злых рекламных.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

стили

```
.title
position: relative
border: 1px solid #afafb0
border-radius: 10px
background-color: #f6f6f6
&:before
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    width: 15px
    height: 1px
    transform: rotate(135deg)
    bottom: -6px
    left: 65px
    background-color: #afafb0
&:after
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    width: 15px
    height: 1px
    transform: rotate(-135deg)
    bottom: -6px
    left: 55px
    background-color: #afafb0
&-wrapper
    p
        margin: 0
        padding: 20px 30px
        line-height: 24px
        text-align: left
        font-size: 12px
        line-height: 20px
        color: #333
```

Нужна помощь с bgc самого треугольника и кусочек border самой подсказки нужно как-то скрыть , что б получилось вот так:
[image: прошу помощи в доработке вёрстки]

пока получается следующее:
[image: Вот вид моего кода]

Comment: Вопрос, а почему не svg?

Comment: Условие проекта - на чистом css

Comment: Можно вопрос, а смысл? У вас реальных задач нет?

Comment: А если условие будет зубной счёткой квартиру подмести?

Comment: Если вы не можете помочь, хоть не мешайте плиз. Зайдут знающие люди и помогут. спс без обид.

Comment: я могу, но вы забиваете гвозди шуруповёртом

Comment: Так помогите - сам треугольник получается сделать , с бордером проблемы

Comment: придётся слегка подождать, я пишу с телефона, вот дойду до компа и отвечу

Comment: Конечно подожду доброго человека! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот грязьненько, в плане перекрытия блоков, если так плохо - скажите

```css
div.title {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #afafb0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
div.title:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 65px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-right: 1px solid #afafb0;
    border-top: 1px solid #afafb0;
}
div.title-wrapper p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div>        
    <div class="title">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
        <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Все знаках, составитель, пунктуация они предложения родного там большой великий на берегу рукописи, за рыбными то бросил заманивший взгляд злых рекламных.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Полностью устраивает! Спасибо добрый человек.

Comment: @Ross наздоровье, но лучше svg